# Maven Project Requires Local Dependency to be Built

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-3, pom.xml

I have 2 Maven projects, A and B. Project A is entirely independent, while B requires A as a dependency. Currently, B is getting A from the maven repository:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

What I would like to do is set up the dependency such that B can reference the local instance of A. I can do the following:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${basedir}/../projectA/target/projectA-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

but this only works if A is already built (so `projectA-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` already exists).

Is there a way to force A to build before B in cases where I don't already have a build of A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is you create a parent pom, and add these projects as child modules. So, the directory structure would look like this:

```
+ pom.xml
|
+-A
|  \ 
|   + pom.xml
+-B 
   \
    + pom.xml
```

The parent pom would have `<modules>` tag, adding `A` and `B` projects as child modules:

```
<groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>A</module>
    <module>B</module>
<modules>
```

And then, add `A` module as dependency to `B` module. Just keep the group-id same for parent, A and B. And then refer the module using artifact-id.

`pom.xml` for `B` would be like:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>projectB</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now, build the parent pom. It will take care of build order.

Comment: This is close to what I want it to do, but when I get rid of  the `<systemPath>` property, it defaults to searching the maven repo for `projectA-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` rather than using the local one. Is there a way to force it to check locally first?

Comment: You don't need to give `systemPath` now. That's the module dependency there.

Comment: Got it working now. I had changed the groupId to test if it was actually working locally, but forgot to update it on one of the child modules.